# What is the "right" way to do this partial function application in C++ without a macro?

Tags: c++, optimization, lambda, c++17, currying

As a simplified example, suppose I start with something like the following code:

```
void function1 (Object &myObject) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 10000; b++) {
        // ... a bunch of code that uses the below myFunction(int, int) in different ways
        auto x = myObject.myFunction(12345, b);
        // do something with x and etc
    }
}
```

and what I want to do is take what's inside the for loop, put it in a separate inline function that is called instead, and somehow grant that function access to a curried version of `myObject.myFunction(a, b)` in which `b` is already set.

One way to do that is this:

```
__attribute__((always_inline))
inline void function2 (Object &myObject, int &b) {
#define curried(a) myObject.myFunction(a, b)
    // ... a bunch of code that uses the below function in different ways
    auto x = curried(12345);
    // do something with x and etc
}

void function1 (Object &myObject) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 10000; b++) {
        function2(myObject, b);
    }
}
```

Which, if you can get the compiler to successfully inline `function2`, yields the same assembly code with no overhead. (Which may require at least -O1 or -O2, at least with clang, even if `__attribute__((always_inline))` is used.)

Either way, it is somewhat awkward to use macros in this situation, and have to pass the value of `b` from `function1` to `function2`. It would be much better to do something like pass a lambda function as a parameter to `function2`, but then I've run into problems with captures (you can only pass an un-captured lambda, but we would need to capture myObject), and also some additional overhead. As an example, I'd like to do this:

```
__attribute__((always_inline))
inline void function2 (some_type curried) {
    // ... a bunch of code that uses the below function in different ways
    auto x = curried(12345);
    // do something with x and etc
}

void function1 (Object &myObject) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 10000; b++) {
        auto lambda = [&](int a) {return myObject.myFunction(a, n);};
        function2(lambda);
    }
}
```

But this fails unless the lambda has no captures, as there is no type that fits into "some_type."

So my question:

Is there any *right* way to do this that is zero-overhead, at least with some minimal optimization?

Comment: Why not use lambda: `auto curried = [&](auto a) { return myObject.myFunction(a, b);}`?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization turn on?

Comment: `inline` is just a *suggestion*. It's up to the compiler to decide if it should actually inline the call.'

Comment: Your inlining relates to `function2`, it has not effect on the call `myObject.myFunction(12345, b)`. In fact you just added another layer that the compiler might not be able to completely optimize out - instead of just directly calling it - and that's probably the reason for the added overhead

Answer (score 1):

A lambda should do the job

```
    auto curried = [&](auto& a) { return myObject.myFunction(a, b);}
```

or

```
    auto curried = [&](const auto& a) { return myObject.myFunction(a, b);}
```

Whether you use one or the other will depend on whether your function is supposed to modify `a` as an in-out parameter. You should be careful if `myObject` or `b` goes out of scope before `curried`, as the lambda will contain a dangling reference.

Also note that lambdas are [only available since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Am I passing the lambda to `function2` or still passing `b` and just replacing the #define?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia You _call_ the lambda like you'd do it for any function `auto x = curried(1234); `

Comment: What I mean is, are you just replacing the `#define` in `function2` with the lambda, or are you changing the signature of `function2` to take the lambda as a parameter?

Comment: I think my issue was, to do what I wanted, you need to pass the lambda as a function parameter to function2. But, you can't do this if the lambda has any captures, because it isn't convertible to a function pointer, because it has a weird temporary data type. But, you *can* do this if the function you are passing to is declared as a template, so that did it for me.